# Is there a cleaner/shorter way to select-replace in matrices?

Tags: matrix

I love *Mathematica*, but I find it oddly lacking when it comes to how matrices are handled.  Here is an example of code that *works* but seems like it should be a lot shorter (and minus the loop).

I'm a super-newbie though so maybe one of you smart people has an idea for making this nicer. The point is to take all elements of the matrix that evaluate as `True` for some criterion (here, being less than 7) and re-assign them to a new value.

```
testmat = {{-1, 1, -3}, {10, 11, 5}, {15, -2, 7}};
MatrixForm[testmat]
badpos = Position[testmat, _?(# < 7 &)];
{nend, trash} = Dimensions[badpos];
For[i = 1, i <= nend, i++,
  selpos = badpos[[i]];
  p1 = selpos[[1]];
  p2 = selpos[[2]];
  testmat[[p1, p2]] = 0;
]
MatrixForm[testmat]
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `ReplacePart`? Using it would eliminate all your code starting at line 4.  (I found a reference to it in the help system by searching for "Part", knowing this is the basic function involved in accessing matrix elements.)

Comment: Is this what you want? `newmat = testmat /. x_ /; x < 7 -> 0`

Comment: Hello and welcome to _Mathematica_ Stack Exchange! Your question was asked before and has several excellent answers with detailed methods to perform select and replace operations, including Szabolcs' answer below. I recommend you look through that in detail for solutions :)

Answer (score 5):

You can [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Replace.html) at [level 2](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LevelsInExpressions.html):

```
Replace[testmat, x_ /; x < 7 -> 0, {2}]
```

An alternative, MATLAB-style vectorized solution is

```
UnitStep[testmat - 7] testmat
```

This second approach is beneficial for performance in certain cases (but not always).  In this case it is going to be considerably faster for very large matrices.

It can be simplified to

```
BoolEval[testmat >= 7] testmat
```

using [this package](https://bitbucket.org/szhorvat/booleval/src).

Comment: Thanks everyone.  I'm very impressed with the terseness possible if you know the commands!  I apologize for the duplicate, I *DID* search but a lot of times when you are very ignorant it's hard just to hit the right terms, I guess.

Comment: @ETM Don't worry, sometimes I remember that there is a duplicate but I still cannot find it easily ... this time I didn't even remember even though I posted a answer in the duplicate question as well.

Comment: @Szabolcs In any case, it's better to post an answer twice than a question ... twice